# Display vertex information using JUNG library

Tags: java, swing, jung

When a user clicks on a vertex i want to set visible a panel that displays (some of) the vertex's properties (The JUNG tutorial explains the same behavior using PopUp menus). Could someone plz give explain which plugin i have to use for that?

thanks for any tip,

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you'd need your own plugin for this.  Basically you just need to listen for clicks on the vertices, though, so you can use the existing plugins for guidance on most of it.  Populating and making visible the panel is up to you.